# Transfer Worksheet to New Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Incredibly novice with excel VBA.  I've found this question in many different places but can't seem to manipulate the code I've tried to work.  Essentially, I have a workbook that creates a new workbook, copies one sheet entirely, saves the workbook, and then needs to transfer a second sheet from the original workbook.  I've gotten it done with this:

```
Wb1.Sheets("Scorecard").Range("A1:M37").Value(11) = Wb.Sheets("Scorecard").Range("A1:M37").Value(11)
```

where Wb1 is the "transfer to" book and Wb is the "transfer from" workbook.  The problem is this doesn't the headers/footers, picture (logo), or hide columns that are meant to be hidden.

I've tried this but it just seems to open another book and freeze my system and open up a third book:

```
Wb.Sheets("Scorecard").Copy
Wb1.Sheets("Scorecard").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious but I'm tired of banging my head against the wall on this.  Full code up this point is below:

```
Sub NewWb()
Dim Aname As String
Dim HospName As String
Dim DateDone As String
Dim xPath As String
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim Wb1 As Workbook
Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
Aname = "CS Diversion Prevention Assessment"
HospName = Sheets("Hospital ID").Range("I8")
DateDone = Replace((Sheets("Hospital ID").Range("I13").Text), "/", "-")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Compliance Checklist").Copy
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  .Value = .Value
End With
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").Delete
Sheets.Add.Name = "Scorecard"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & HospName & "." & Aname & "." &     DateDone & ".xlsx"
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open(xPath & "\" & HospName & "." & Aname & "." & DateDone & ".xlsx")

Wb.Activate
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me on Excel 2013, using the [`Worksheet.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.aspx) method.  I also tried a move, using the [`Worksheet.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834742.aspx) method, but it took ~10 seconds to move the sheet (!).

```
Public Sub copy_it_buster()
    Dim to_copy As Worksheet, copy_after As Worksheet
    Set to_copy = Workbooks("Book2").Sheets(1)  ' Or whatever worksheet you're moving from 
    Set copy_after = Workbooks("Book3").Sheets(1)  ' Or whatever worksheet you want to copy after.
        ' Note that this is in a different workbook!
    to_copy.Copy After:=copy_after
    'to_copy.Move After:=copy_after ' if you don't want to keep it where
                                    ' it was originally
End Sub
```

**Edit 2**: After copying, to convert all the formulas to flat values, try this courtesy of [Ron de Bruin's MVP site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win015.htm):

```
dim sh as Worksheet
set sh = ' whatever your new worksheet is
With sh.UsedRange
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

**Edit** For the `Move` case I originally tested, when I started with:

```
Book2                   Book3
Sheet1                  Sheet1
```

I wound up with:

```
no Book2!               Book3
                        Sheet1    Sheet1 (2)
```

**Edit** for `Copy`, I get:

```
Book2                   Book3
Sheet1                  Sheet1 Sheet1(2)
```

**Note** that this requires the target workbook already exist.  Also, if you want to copy/move to *before* an existing worksheet instead of *after*, just change `After` to `Before` in the `Copy` call.

**And a PS**: To reduce frustration on this and future projects, use names like `FromWorkbook` and `ToWorkbook` rather than `Wb` and `Wb1`.  It may not seem like much, but in my experience it significantly reduces mental workload while debugging!

Comment: Beat me to it! This is copying the workbook object, the whole thing in memory vs putting just the data onto the clipboard.

Comment: My apologies - I should have been more specific in the original post.  I'd like to keep a copy of the sheet in the original file.  The sheet will essentially be copy/pasted as values in the new workbook

Comment: @DChantal Edited - just use `.Copy` instead of `.Move` :)

Comment: Hmm.. Not responding now but I'll have to look over how I added this.  While I'm doing that might as well ask - does this paste it as a value in the new sheet or will it leave the formulas in?  I need it as a value.  Thanks!

Comment: @DChantal when I used `Move` it was nonresponsive for ~10sec - give it a minute to think :/ .  This will clone the worksheet exactly, formulas and all.  See edit I am going to make in just a moment.

Comment: Thanks for the start - I'm on about 8 min and still showing "Not Responding" for me

Comment: @DChantal :( No fun!  What version of Excel, what OS, 32 or 64 bit, and are the files on a local drive or on a network drive?  If network, try copying them to local first and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: cxw - I got it going later last night.  I really need to learn to use the record macro function much more often!  It was select>copy and part of my issue was having the full file path name for the "copy to" workbook in which was giving me a subscript error.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though!

Comment: @DChantal Glad to hear it --- happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered saving/copying the source workbook (Wb) as a new workbook (Wb1), then editing the new one?

So instead of creating a new blank wb and adding to it...  Create a copy of the original, then remove from it what you need.

Comment: I hadn't but I need the two sheets to end up as values because there are ~10 tabs ultimately that would feed back to this.